# How to open a 3rd party website inside VS Code using WebView API?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, webview

The [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview) talks about rendering locally saved HTML using WebView API. But I want to open a 3rd party site from the internet like `https://google.com`. It should open in a VS Code tab, not redirect me to the browser.

Is this functionality supported? If yes, please provide some code samples.